# how to scroll smoothly to see all the items in the tableview in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am doing a tableview which is customized by tableviewcell, but when I scroll it up and down, the last item just shows the half of image (each row has image on the left) and also has no any letter(3 text labels) showed like the other items. How can I make it better to scroll down or up to see all the items?

Comment: Please attach screen shot and add some code from Your TableView or TableViewController

Comment: i don't have enough score to attach the image, i need 10 more!

Comment: here's comes the upvote for the first 5 of the missing 10.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your UITableView is the correct size?

If you have a status bar and navigation bar the tableview should be 416px tall

[image: Interface Builder Screenshot]

Comment: I do the page  scrolling that each page is the tableview and my tableview doesn't have view like your picture !